# Data from some Facebook users not inserting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have a strange, but definitely serious problem regarding fetching data from some Facebook users who authorize my App and use it (normally by the way).

Around 3000 users have used the App so far, but only 600 are showing up in the users table. How could that be possible? I cannot find connection between old and new users - for some it works flawlessly, for others it just doesn't work at all.

Here's the complete, but for security reasons censored code:

```
<?php
 require 'facebook.php';
 include 'config.php';
 session_start();

 $app_id = 'id';
 $app_secret = 'secret';
 $app_namespace = 'namespace';
 $app_url = 'https://apps.facebook.com/' . $app_namespace . '/';
 $scope = 'email,publish_actions';
```

// Init the Facebook SDK

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
    ));
```

// Get the current user

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Auth Dialog

```
 if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => $scope,
    'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
    ));

print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
 }

 else if ($user) {
    try {
```

// Proceed knowing we have a logged in user who's authenticated.

```
    $fbuid = $facebook->getUser();
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');



} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
 }
else{
header('Location: index.php');

 }
 $queryUserExists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook'AND oauth_uid = " . $user_profile['id']);
 $num=mysql_numrows($queryUserExists);
```

//If not, add it to the database

```
 if ($num == 0) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_uid, oauth_provider, username, first_name, last_name, email, pic_square ,login_date , dailytokens) 
        VALUES ({$user_profile['id']}, 'facebook', '{$user_profile['name']}', '{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['email']}', '".$photolink."',CURDATE(),1)");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_uid = " . mysql_insert_id());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
 }
     else
     {
    $DateLastLogin=mysql_result($queryUserExists,0,"login_date");
    $myDate = date('Y-m-d');

    $CompLastDate = strtotime($DateLastLogin);
    $CompMyDate = strtotime($myDate);

if($CompLastDate < $CompMyDate){
    $updateDailyToken = "Update users set login_date=CURDATE(), dailytokens = dailytokens + 1 where oauth_uid =" . $user_profile['id'];
    $updateToken= mysql_query($updateDailyToken) or die(mysql_error());
}
 }
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND oauth_uid = " . $user_profile['id']);

 $_SESSION['userid']=$user_profile['id'];
```

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.

```
     if ($user) {
    $paramsout = array('next'=>'http://facebook.com');
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($paramsout);
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the object type in the database. Some facebook users have incredebly large id: 0098788563000236 for example, so using BIGINT instead of INT solved it.

Answer (score 1):

here is your problem

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_uid, oauth_provider, username, first_name, last_name, email, pic_square ,login_date , dailytokens) 
        VALUES ({$user_profile['id']}, 'facebook', '{$user_profile['name']}', '{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['email']}', '".$photolink."',CURDATE(),1)");
```

it should be

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_uid, oauth_provider, username, first_name, last_name, email, pic_square ,login_date , dailytokens) 
        VALUES ('{$user_profile['id']}', 'facebook', '{$user_profile['name']}', '{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['email']}', '{$photolink}',CURDATE(),1)");
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! But I'm afraid it doesn't work. To be precise, it works the same way as before. I've deleted all users, and tried to login with few accounts of my mates (they have all authorized App); some of them are in the users table, but the others are not.

Comment: Update (if it helps): I have even removed permissions from those FB accounts, and reauthorized App - still nothing...

Comment: i have done up-vote so now you have got the permission for chat please discuss this on [chat ](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)